# How to fetch data in mongoDB and show by years in a row?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am getting an array of data from MongoDB, contains `id`, `userName`, `date`. Date contains `years and months`. I want to show this data by years. How can I make a query to DB, to show data of all years.

Data:

```
[
    {
        "id": "101",
        "userName": "John",
        "date": "2023-03-20"
    },
    {
        "id": "102",
        "userName": "Deo",
        "date": "2023-01-11"
    },
    {
        "id": "102",
        "userName": "Yeh",
        "date": "2023-1-11"
    },
    {
        "id": "103",
        "userName": "Swim",
        "date": "2021-11-14"
    },
    {
        "id": "104",
        "userName": "Piter",
        "date": "2021-06-21"
    },
    {
        "id": "105",
        "userName": "yogo",
        "date": "2021-10-05"
    }
]
```

Data contains `year from 2023 - 2021` I need to display this data by years present in data but having issue that how to show it.

Comment: So, you want the data grouped by year?

Comment: yes, I want to group that by years, it is not necessary that years will be continue. For each user it may be different.

Comment: And as what type is the date saved?

Comment: Date format is - 
createdAt: 2023-02-27T06:04:44.020+00:00

Answer (score 1):

Use Aggregation Pipeline Operators, First Group data year wise then push other fields.

[Check it out](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/upcoming/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)

that Date is in string??

Assuming your date field is stored as a string in the format "YYYY-MM-DD", you can use the following query
[Playground link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TsYzxvJ5O67)

Ok if your data is in Date format then check below

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EQm12nYMWJw)

```
    db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      year: {
        $year: {
          $toDate: "$date"
        }
      },
      id: 1,
      userName: 1,
      date: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$year",
      documents: {
        $push: {
          id: "$id",
          userName: "$userName",
          date: "$date"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      _id: 1
    }
  }
])
```

this will give the exact output you needed, first rearrange collections by using `project` then group it by using $year in _id for your need if you want to group data by another field change _id in $group , also if you want to rearrange years then try using -1 in sort.

Comment: Hi I am getting empty response - 

`
"myEntries": {
        "_events": {},
        "_eventsCount": 0
    }
`

Comment: can you share your pipeline? also a copy of the DB where you are getting that response